# smarty tpl files are cached, updating nor possible

Tags: caching, smarty

Somehow all tpl files are beeing cached - at least I think so...

If I want to update a file I need to rename it, updating the file will always output the previous version, even if it is deleted on the server.
How do I fix that?

*btw: I use smarty because I have to, not beacause I want to (old system not updated in the last 15 years), thats why I dont really know my way around. I couldnt find a adaquate answer with google...*

Does this help and if so how do I use it?
https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/caching.tpl

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation from the link you included, that's what you can do:

- Disable caching totally for a template by setting `$smarty->caching = 0;` where `$smarty` is your template.
- You can manually clear the cache for a template using `$smarty->clear_cache('template_name.tpl');` or for all templates `$smarty->clear_all_cache();`.
- If for some reason none of the above helped, you can manually delete the compiled versions of your templates. They are in a directory defined in variable [$cache_dir](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/variable.cache.dir.tpl).
- You can even write a script that will clear this directory independent of smarty. However for me it is a hack and inelegant solution.
- If you have troubles finding the directory with cached templates you can search it by your template file name. Compiled version of smarty template is just a php file which contains among others the name of template it was compiled from. This file has a long random name. When you have a file, you can check a directory where it is situated - it should be your directory with cached templates.

Comment: If I have no access to the server that means there is no way for me to clear the cache. I can only write .tpl files to 'style' the output...

Comment: _even if it is deleted on the server_ suggests that you have access to the server. Like I said you can manually delete files from compile (temp) directory. If you don't have access - ask about it. I can see no other solution.